# AutoMapper - ProjectTo class with multiple properties of the same type

Tags: c#, automapper

Recently found out about AutoMapper's [ProjectTo<>](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html) method, so I've been playing around with it.

So far so good until I came upon a class that had multiple properties of the same type, such as:

```
public class RandomDto
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public ChildDto FirstChild {get;set;}
    public ChildDto SecondChild {get;set;}
}
```

It seems like it generates SQL for a single Child relationship, and not for both:

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN [dtoRandom].[FirstChild_FK] IS NULL
    THEN CAST(1 AS BIT) ELSE CAST(0 AS BIT)
END, [t0].[Child_Description]
END, [dtoRandom].[Id]
FROM [Randoms] AS [dtoRandom]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [s].*
    FROM [Childs] AS [s]
) AS [t0] ON [dtoRandom].[FirstChild_FK] = [t0].[Id]
```

I've tried

```
.ProjectTo<RandomDto>(null, "FirstChild", "SecondChild")
.ProjectTo<RandomDto>(x=>x.FirstChild, x=>x.SecondChild)
```

and both return with the first one being filled in, second being null

Not sure if I need to set custom aliases or something for this to work?

Comment: Try writing that as a LINQ query, without AM.

Comment: I am having the same issue. If I take out one of the properties that has the same type, it works. This sounds like a bug in Auto Mapper (currently I am using v9.0.0), although I tried to simulate the problem on a simpler test application but it didn't happen. Apparently it's not *only* about having two or more properties of the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same behaviour and tried to work around the problem by using an other class for the second navigation property that only derived from the original one.

```
public class ChildDtoTmp : ChildDto { }

public class RandomDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ChildDto FirstChild { get; set; }
    public ChildDtoTmp SecondChild { get; set; }
}
```

This worked fine, but because the type of the navigation proerty has another navigation property the same strange behaviour shows up with the nested navigation property.

```
public class ChildDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public InnerChildDto InnerChild { get; set; }
}
```

This leads to the properties `FirstChild` and `SecondChild` being mapped, but only the `InnerChild` property of the `FirstChild` gets mapped.

Maybe this helps someone to figure out how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue *might* be related to a slightly confusing option called `MaxDepth`. I've managed to reproduce that exact problem by calling `MaxDepth(1)`, which in my understanding should only affect self-referencing entities such as:

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo InnerFoo { get; set; }
}
```

In that case, a `MaxDepth(1)` should only map the first `Foo` found in a object graph. Which is exactly what it happens, but it also affects the following structure (quite wrongly, IMHO):

```
class Bar
{
    public Foo Foo1 { get; set; }
    public Foo Foo2 { get; set; }
}
```

A `MaxDepth(1)` in the above scenario will map only the `Foo1` property, keeping `Foo2` as `null`.

Oh, by the way: to set `MaxDepth`, one may apply to all their mappings:

```
var mapperCfg = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddProfile<SomeProfile>();
    cfg.ForAllMaps(SetMaxDepth);
});

private static void SetMaxDepth(TypeMap typeMap, IMappingExpression expression) => expression.MaxDepth(1);
```

Or to each map individually:

```
var mapperCfg = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<SomeObject, SomeObjectDto>().MaxDepth(1);
});
```